# Parse text field and join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

Table Heroes - 2 records

```
Name NVARCHAR(50)
PowerIds NVARCHAR(50) 

Name               PowerIds
'Hulk'             '1,3'
'Reed Richards'    '2'
```

Table Powers - 3 records

```
PowerId INT
PowerDescr NVARCHAR(50)

PowerId   PowerDescr
1         'Strength'
2         'Intelligence'
3         'Durability'
```

What would be the smartest way to achieve this in a SELECT:

```
Name               Powers
'Hulk'             'Strength, Durability'
'Reed Richards'    'Intelligence'
```

**I cannot change the table structure, since this is a third party product.**

Answer (score 4):

The smartest way would be to normalize your table. Change the `Heroes` table to

```
Name               PowerId
'Hulk'             1
'Hulk'             3
'Reed Richards'    2
```

or remove the power from the `Heroes` table and add another table that holds only the reference to a hero and the powers like this

```
HeroID  PowerID
1       1
1       3
2       2
```

### Never store multiple data in one column!

Comment: Thanks. I added an important disclaimer to my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT Name,
STUFF(
  (SELECT ',' + CAST(P.PowerDescr as VARCHAR(MAX))
  FROM fn_ParseCsvString(H1.PowerIds, ',') H2
  INNER JOIN Powers P ON P.PowerId = H2.ParsedString 
  FOR XML path('')),1,1,''
) AS Strength
FROM Heroes H1
```

Function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ParseCsvString]
(   
    @csvString  VARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter  VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @parsedStringTable TABLE (ParsedString VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @startIndex INT, @targetedIndex INT
    SELECT
        @startIndex = 1
    WHILE @startIndex <= LEN(@CSVString)
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            @targetedIndex = charindex(@Delimiter, @CSVString, @startIndex)
        IF @targetedIndex = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT  
                @targetedIndex = len(@CSVString) + 1
        END
        INSERT  @parsedStringTable 
        SELECT 
            SUBSTRING(@CSVString, @startIndex, @targetedIndex - @startIndex)
        SELECT  @startIndex = @targetedIndex + LEN(@Delimiter)
    END
    RETURN
END


GO
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b94e) you can find a SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: Invalid object name 'fn_ParseCsvString'

Comment: Please check this again .